# Why the same arabic string shows differently in Windows 7 and Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: 12.04, vim

The same arabic string, in windows 7 Notepad: [image: ar in notepad]

in ubuntu linux vi: [image: ar in vi]

They are the same string in a file, but the display order is opposite, why?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same encoding? Ubuntu will most likely be using UTF.

Comment: @Rinzwind it is a same string in a same file ar.txt

Comment: Sure but the -encoding- of the file matters. Do a `file ar.txt` in Ubuntu. It will show the encoding. If Notepad is openend with a different encoding you get different results.

Comment: As far as I know vim is text based and may not display complex scripts correctly. How does it show in `gedit`?

Comment: @VictorS, in which terminal did you run vim?